# The program displays area as '0'

Tags: java, methods

The program calculates the area and volume of a sphere. It is a homework question so, cant change much of the format.

The main issue I think here is the variable scope but, I'm unable to identify it.

```
import  java.util.*;

class Data

{

     double r;
     public void gdata()

     {

          System.out.println("Enter Radius");
          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
          r=s.nextFloat();
     }

}

class Area extends Data

{

     double area;
     public void calculate()
     {area = r*r*3.14;}
     public void display()

    {

        Area obj = new Area();
        obj.calculate();
        System.out.println("Area of Circle= "+area);}

    }
}

class  Volume extends Area 

{

    final double pi=3.141;
    double v;
    public void calculate()
    {v=(4*r*r*r*pi)/3;}
    public void display()

    {   

        Volume obj = new Volume();
        obj.calculate();
        System.out.println("Volume of Sphere= "+v);}

    }


class Postlab

{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        Area obj1 = new Area();
        Area obj2 = new Volume();
        obj1.display();
        obj2.display();

    }

}
```

Comment: You're calling calculate on the wrong object. It should be called on `this`

Comment: You should use `Math.PI` instead of 3.14 to get a more accurate result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is :-

1. You were never calling the `gData()` that will initialize your radius.
2. You were creating a new object when you were calling `display()`.
   instead of calling `calculate()` from same object.

Please find the working code below :-

```
import  java.util.*;

class Data

{

    double r;
    public void gdata()

    {

        System.out.println("Enter Radius");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        r=s.nextFloat();
    }

}

class Area extends Data

{

    double area;
    public void calculate()
    {area = r*r*3.14;}
    public void display()

    {

        this.gdata();
        this.calculate();
        System.out.println("Area of Circle= "+area);}

}


class  Volume extends Area

{

    final double pi=3.141;
    double v;
    public void calculate()
    {v=(4*r*r*r*pi)/3;}
    public void display()

    {

        this.gdata();
        this.calculate();
        System.out.println("Volume of Sphere= "+v);}

}


class Postlab

{

    public static void main(String args[])

    {

        Area obj1 = new Area();
        Area obj2 = new Volume();
        obj1.display();
        obj2.display();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point you have to call `Data`'s `gdata()` as otherwise `r` will always be 0.